# Android Application size difference when using emulator and device?

Tags: android

I am loading *5000 images* with *3.16MB size* of image.

When i load application into *emualtor( Froyo 2.2)* it shows *325 MB size* of the application.

But when i load the same application into *tablet device* it shows *1.38GB*.

Can any one explain me why it happens?

Comment: @AliImran no its not bug.

Comment: why it happens?I think it should be the same size in both device and emulator